# RegEx npp - having trouble with lookaround matching

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a complicated bit of text I wish to search/delete from frequent output documents. (See bottom of question for source text)

**Using the regex, I wish to:**
Leave lines like this: `1234TH-ST-TA5000-1#sh in sh 1/7/12 re`
Delete this: `several lines of whitespace`
Stop before this line: `-------------------------------`

My current regex uses lookaround to begin matching AFTER the first line, but for some reason it includes the first line in the match and only finds the first instance (there are six or seven that should be matched/removed).

Current RegEx: `(?:(\r|\n|\r\n).+-TA5000-\d\#sh in sh \d+\/\d+\/\d+ re\b)\s+`

<kbd>[**RegEx101 Fiddle to play with**](https://regex101.com/r/dbkvO2/1)</kbd>

Source text:

```html
1234TH-ST-TA5000-1#sh in sh 1/7/12 re































                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SHDSL 1/7/12                                                                    
  Description                      690686                                       
  Admin Status                     In Service                                   
  Oper Status                      Up                                           
  Channel Rate (kbps)              2624                                         
  ES                               0                                            
  SES                              0                                            
  UAS                              0                                            
  CVC                              0                                            
  LOSWS                            0                                            
  Retrains                         0                                            
  Handshake Failures               0                                            
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         18,18,18 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    18,6,18 (Cur, Min, Max)                      
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,17,17 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            15,15,15 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  Upstream PBO (dB)                0                                            
  Downstream PBO (dB)              0                                            
  Annex                            A/B/EFM                                      
  Line Probe                       Disabled                                     
(OUTPUT TRUNCATED)--------------------------------------------------------------
 Exit - 'Ctrl-C', Clear - 'c', Freeze - 'f', Resume - 'r'                       




















SHDSL 1/7/12 
  Description                      690686
  Admin Status                     In Service
  Oper Status                      Up
  Channel Rate (kbps)              2624
  ES                               0
  SES                              0
  UAS                              0
  CVC                              0
  LOSWS                            0
  Retrains                         0
  Handshake Failures               0
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         18,18,18 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    18,6,18 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,17,17 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            15,15,15 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Upstream PBO (dB)                0
  Downstream PBO (dB)              0
  Annex                            A/B/EFM
  Line Probe                       Disabled
  Line Rate (N x DS0s)             41,41,41 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Constellation Crossover (DS0s)   60
  Constellation (bits/baud)        3
1234TH-ST-TA5000-1#sh in sh 1/2/24 re




















                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SHDSL 1/2/24                                                                    
  Description                      689932                                       
  Admin Status                     In Service                                   
  Oper Status                      Up                                           
  Channel Rate (kbps)              832                                          
  ES                               0                                            
  SES                              0                                            
  UAS                              0                                            
  CVC                              0                                            
  LOSWS                            0                                            
  Retrains                         0                                            
  Handshake Failures               0                                            
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         29,29,29 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    29,4,70 (Cur, Min, Max)                      
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,2,4 (Cur, Min, Max)                       
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            6,6,6 (Cur, Min, Max)                        
  Upstream PBO (dB)                3                                            
  Downstream PBO (dB)              4                                            
  Annex                            A/B/EFM                                      
  Line Probe                       Disabled                                     
(OUTPUT TRUNCATED)--------------------------------------------------------------
 Exit - 'Ctrl-C', Clear - 'c', Freeze - 'f', Resume - 'r'                       




















SHDSL 1/2/24 
  Description                      689932
  Admin Status                     In Service
  Oper Status                      Up
  Channel Rate (kbps)              832
  ES                               0
  SES                              0
  UAS                              0
  CVC                              0
  LOSWS                            0
  Retrains                         0
  Handshake Failures               0
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         29,29,29 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    29,4,70 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,2,4 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            6,6,6 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Upstream PBO (dB)                3
  Downstream PBO (dB)              4
  Annex                            A/B/EFM
  Line Probe                       Disabled
  Line Rate (N x DS0s)             13,13,13 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Constellation Crossover (DS0s)   60
  Constellation (bits/baud)        3
1234TH-ST-TA5000-1#sh in sh 1/7/1 re 




















                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SHDSL 1/7/1                                                                     
  Description                                                                   
  Admin Status                     Out of Service - Unassigned                  
  Oper Status                      Down                                         
  Channel Rate (kbps)              0                                            
  ES                               0                                            
  SES                              0                                            
  UAS                              0                                            
  CVC                              0                                            
  LOSWS                            0                                            
  Retrains                         0                                            
  Handshake Failures               0                                            
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         -2,-2,-2 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    0,0,0 (Cur, Min, Max)                        
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,8,12 (Cur, Min, Max)                      
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            27,27,27 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  Upstream PBO (dB)                0                                            
  Downstream PBO (dB)              0                                            
  Annex                            A/B/EFM                                      
  Line Probe                       Worstcase                                    
(OUTPUT TRUNCATED)--------------------------------------------------------------
 Exit - 'Ctrl-C', Clear - 'c', Freeze - 'f', Resume - 'r'                       




















SHDSL 1/7/1 
  Description                      
  Admin Status                     Out of Service - Unassigned
  Oper Status                      Down
  Channel Rate (kbps)              0
  ES                               0
  SES                              0
  UAS                              0
  CVC                              0
  LOSWS                            0
  Retrains                         0
  Handshake Failures               0
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         -2,-2,-2 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    0,0,0 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,8,12 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            27,27,27 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Upstream PBO (dB)                0
  Downstream PBO (dB)              0
  Annex                            A/B/EFM
  Line Probe                       Worstcase
  Worst Case Margin                3
  Line Rate (N x DS0s)             0,3,89 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Constellation Crossover (DS0s)   60
1234TH-ST-TA5000-1#sh in sh 1/7/31 re




















                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SHDSL 1/7/31                                                                    
  Description                      690689                                       
  Admin Status                     In Service                                   
  Oper Status                      Up                                           
  Channel Rate (kbps)              1472                                         
  ES                               0                                            
  SES                              0                                            
  UAS                              0                                            
  CVC                              0                                            
  LOSWS                            0                                            
  Retrains                         0                                            
  Handshake Failures               0                                            
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         26,26,26 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    26,23,27 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,27,27 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            7,7,7 (Cur, Min, Max)                        
  Upstream PBO (dB)                3                                            
  Downstream PBO (dB)              4                                            
  Annex                            A/B/EFM                                      
  Line Probe                       Disabled                                     
(OUTPUT TRUNCATED)--------------------------------------------------------------
 Exit - 'Ctrl-C', Clear - 'c', Freeze - 'f', Resume - 'r'                       




















SHDSL 1/7/31 
  Description                      690689
  Admin Status                     In Service
  Oper Status                      Up
  Channel Rate (kbps)              1472
  ES                               0
  SES                              0
  UAS                              0
  CVC                              0
  LOSWS                            0
  Retrains                         0
  Handshake Failures               0
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         26,26,26 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    26,23,27 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,27,27 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            7,7,7 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Upstream PBO (dB)                3
  Downstream PBO (dB)              4
  Annex                            A/B/EFM
  Line Probe                       Disabled
  Line Rate (N x DS0s)             23,23,23 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Constellation Crossover (DS0s)   60
  Constellation (bits/baud)        3
1234TH-ST-TA5000-1#sh in sh 1/7/32 re




















                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SHDSL 1/7/32                                                                    
  Description                      690690                                       
  Admin Status                     In Service                                   
  Oper Status                      Down                                         
  Channel Rate (kbps)              0                                            
  ES                               0                                            
  SES                              0                                            
  UAS                              1                                            
  CVC                              0                                            
  LOSWS                            1                                            
  Retrains                         0                                            
  Handshake Failures               0                                            
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         -3,-3,-3 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    0,0,0 (Cur, Min, Max)                        
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,0,8 (Cur, Min, Max)                       
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            46,46,46 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  Upstream PBO (dB)                0                                            
  Downstream PBO (dB)              0                                            
  Annex                            A/B/EFM                                      
  Line Probe                       Disabled                                     
(OUTPUT TRUNCATED)--------------------------------------------------------------
 Exit - 'Ctrl-C', Clear - 'c', Freeze - 'f', Resume - 'r'                       




















SHDSL 1/7/32 
  Description                      690690
  Admin Status                     In Service
  Oper Status                      Down
  Channel Rate (kbps)              0
  ES                               0
  SES                              0
  UAS                              2
  CVC                              0
  LOSWS                            2
  Retrains                         0
  Handshake Failures               0
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         -3,-3,-3 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    0,0,0 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,0,8 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            46,46,46 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Upstream PBO (dB)                0
  Downstream PBO (dB)              0
  Annex                            A/B/EFM
  Line Probe                       Disabled
  Line Rate (N x DS0s)             0,20,20 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Constellation Crossover (DS0s)   60
  Constellation (bits/baud)        N/A
1234TH-ST-TA5000-1#sh in sh 1/7/10 re




















                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SHDSL 1/7/10                                                                    
  Description                      690685                                       
  Admin Status                     In Service                                   
  Oper Status                      Down                                         
  Channel Rate (kbps)              0                                            
  ES                               57020                                        
  SES                              92                                           
  UAS                              132288                                       
  CVC                              138706                                       
  LOSWS                            131657                                       
  Retrains                         728                                          
  Handshake Failures               0                                            
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         -2,-8,20 (Cur, Min, Max)                     
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    0,0,0 (Cur, Min, Max)                        
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,6,10 (Cur, Min, Max)                      
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            20,8,37 (Cur, Min, Max)                      
  Upstream PBO (dB)                0                                            
  Downstream PBO (dB)              1                                            
  Annex                            A/B/EFM                                      
  Line Probe                       Disabled                                     
(OUTPUT TRUNCATED)--------------------------------------------------------------
 Exit - 'Ctrl-C', Clear - 'c', Freeze - 'f', Resume - 'r'                       




















SHDSL 1/7/10 
  Description                      690685
  Admin Status                     In Service
  Oper Status                      Down
  Channel Rate (kbps)              0
  ES                               0
  SES                              0
  UAS                              0
  CVC                              0
  LOSWS                            0
  Retrains                         0
  Handshake Failures               0
  SNR Margin Absolute (dB)         -2,-2,-2 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Current Train (dB)    0,0,0 (Cur, Min, Max)
  SNR Margin Previous Train (dB)   na,6,10 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Loop Attenuation (dB)            20,20,20 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Upstream PBO (dB)                0
  Downstream PBO (dB)              1
  Annex                            A/B/EFM
  Line Probe                       Disabled
  Line Rate (N x DS0s)             0,19,19 (Cur, Min, Max)
  Constellation Crossover (DS0s)   60
  Constellation (bits/baud)        N/A
1234TH-ST-TA5000-1#
```

Comment: Not sure what you need - just remove the empty lines after that specific line? Like [here](https://regex101.com/r/F9vf9w/1)?

Comment: Yes, please add that as the answer - I see you got it. I was hoping to leave the conditional `(\r|\n|\r\n)` but I can live without it Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(^.+-TA5000-\d#sh in sh \d+/\d+/\d+ re$)\s+
```

and replace with `$1\n`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F9vf9w/1).

Note that Notepad++ regexps do not use regex delimiters, there is no need escaping a forward slash.

Also, NPP regex uses the multiline option by default, `^` matches the start of a *line*, thus, I enabled `m` option at regex101.com when testing. I also enabled `g` option there to look for multiple matches (to emulate *Replace All*).

**Pattern details**:

- `(^.+-TA5000-\d#sh in sh \d+/\d+/\d+ re$)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern):

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `.+` - any 1+ chars other than line break symbols
  - `-TA5000-` - a literal substring
  - `\d` - a digit
  - `#sh in sh`  - a literal substring
  - `\d+/\d+/\d+` - 1+ digits, `/`, 1+ digits, `/`, 1+ digits
  - `re` - a literal " re" substring
  - `$` - the end of line
- `\s+` - 1 or more any whitespace symbols (these will get removed).

Comment: Your guesses/assumptions re NPP are spot on. Thanks

Comment: @crashwap: If you want to avoid matching this specific line at the start of a file, then yes, a linebreak before it should be captured as well. Replace `^` with `\R` in my above regex.